# Python socket - receive from server not working

Tags: python, sockets

I'm having an issue with a Python socket client and server - I want the following exchange:

- Client sends message to server.
- Server reads message and makes a decision based on it.
- Server sends appropriate message back to client.

I'm getting stuck on the last point. No matter what I try, the client won't receive the message sent by the server. Refer to code below:

Client:

```
import socket, select

ip = ["10.189.165.14", 25565]

# Client class to manage server connections
class Client:
    def __init__(self, ip:list):
        self.sock = socket.socket() # Create the socket object
        ip[1] = int(ip[1]) # Convert the port number provided into an int
        self.ip = tuple(ip) # Save the inputted IP and port (sock.connect requires a tuple, so convert it here)

    def connect(self):
        """Method to attempt to connect to the server"""
        self.sock.settimeout(3) # Set the timeout period that the client will try to connect for
        self.sock.connect(self.ip) # Connection to the host and port
        self.conn = self.sock # Set self.conn = self.sock, for consistent variable naming with the server code
        self.sock.setblocking(False) # Set socket to be non-blocking so it errors with BlockingIOError instead of blocking the connection
        print("This is the CLIENT; Connected to server")
        return True # Return True to the caller so it knows a successful connection has been established

    def recv_info(self):
        """Method to receive information from the server in an x byte string"""
        for _ in range(100): # Run this method multiple times, until the incoming variable receives information
            incoming, _, _ = select.select([self.conn], [], [], 0.01) # Monitor incoming messages from the socket
            if incoming: # If there is an incoming message from the server
                dataRecv = []
                while True: # Infinite loop to break the received bytes data into chunks and load them individually
                    packet = b"" # Reset packet to a blank byte string
                    try:
                        packet = self.conn.recv(4096) # Receive data from server into packet
                    except BlockingIOError: # If packet gets nothing from the recv()
                        break # Break out of this while loop
                    if not packet:
                        break # If the packet has received nothing from the connection, break this loop
                    dataRecv.append(packet) # Add the packet onto dataRecv

                return dataRecv # Return the received message

client = Client(ip) # Create the client object
conn = client.connect() # Establish a connection with the server
if conn == True: # If connection is successful

    client.conn.sendall(b"Send to server") # Send message to the server
    print("Sent to server")

    recv = client.recv_info() # Look for message from the server
    print(f"Received {recv} from server")
```

Server:

```
import socket, select

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket() # Create the socket object upon instantiation
        self.ip = (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 25565) # Make machine name, socket and port visible to the outside world
        self.sock.bind(self.ip) # Bind the IP and port to the socket

    def connect(self):
        """Method to connect to a client socket"""
        self.sock.settimeout(5) # Set the timeout period that the server will wait for a connection
        self.sock.listen(5) # Number of allowed unaccepted connections before refusing new connections (i.e. connection queue length)
        try:
            self.conn, addr = self.sock.accept() # Wait to establish connection with an outside client
        except socket.timeout: # If the timeout period elapses without a connection
            return False # Exit this method

        print("This is the SERVER; Connected to client")
        self.sock.setblocking(False) # Set socket to be non-blocking so it errors with BlockingIOError instead of blocking the connection
        return True # Return True so the caller knows that a connection has been established

    def recv_info(self):
        """Method to receive information from the client in an x byte string"""
        for _ in range(100): # Run this method multiple times, until the incoming variable receives information
            incoming, _, _ = select.select([self.conn], [], [], 0.01) # Monitor incoming messages from the socket
            if incoming: # If there is an incoming message from the client

                dataRecv = [] # Start dataRecv as an empty list for this _ iteration
                while True: # Infinite loop while receiving data
                    packet = b"" # Reset packet to a blank byte string
                    try:
                        packet = self.conn.recv(4096) # Receive data from client into packet
                    except BlockingIOError: # If self.conn.recv() is blocked
                        break # Break out of this while loop
                    if not packet: # If packet gets nothing from the recv()
                        break # Break out of this while loop
                    dataRecv.append(packet) # Add the packet onto dataRecv
                    # self.conn.sendall(b"Send to client")

                print(f"Received {dataRecv} from client")
                # Decision making logic to decide on what msg should be
                msg = b"Send to client"

                self.conn.sendall(msg)
                print("Sent to client")

                break # Break out of the outer incoming attempts loop

server = Server() # Initialise the server

serverRunning = True
while serverRunning == True: # This boolean always starts as True

    conn = server.connect() # Check for a client connection; will return True or False
    if conn == True:
        # When a connection is established, receive information from the client
        server.recv_info() # recv_info() contains an infinite loop to receive information
```

Running this gives the output:

Client:

This is the CLIENT; Connected to server

Sent to server

Received None from server

Server:

This is the SERVER; Connected to client

Sent to client

Received [b'Send to server'] from client

Which is not working as the client has received nothing.

If you uncomment the line

```
self.conn.sendall(b"Send to client")
```

in Server.recv_info() then suddenly, it works. But I need to keep the sendall outside of the while True loop I think, in case the incoming message is split over multiple packets? I'm not sure why this would work when a sendall outside the loop does not.

I think that there must be something about sockets I'm not understanding here. I've played around with blocking/not-blocking, closing the socket connection, adding wait times, and read a lot of questions on here (closest I've found is [I got problems with making a Python socket server receive commands from a Python socket client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968504/i-got-problems-with-making-a-python-socket-server-receive-commands-from-a-python)), but to no avail. Any ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: Have you tried any of the very many examples on the interweb of a python tcp socket server, e.g. https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html

Comment: Alas I have, including the one you've linked. None I've found though have my combination of looping through self.conn.recv() and the server needing to send back to the client only after all the data is received.

Comment: I wasn’t asking you to make a comparison. I was saying “have you tried STARTING from this example and evolving it into what you want to do - i.e. start from something that works in one situation - the emphasis being on “works” - and develop it incrementally to solve your problem. Take one step at a time. Change one thing then test that worked.